# Location is returning nil

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, location, cllocationmanager

I have been stuck on this problem all day. My app is not updating with the location after the user selects "allow location while in use" causing nothing but nil to appear everywhere

originally I was using mapView.userLocation as a way to find the users location but when I started using CLLocationManager it stopped working.

from the top I imported CoreLocation and add CLLocationManagerDelegate in my class.

Above the viewDidLoad() I have 
    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
and in the viewDidLoad I have 
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest

Now the way that I am going about checking wether the user has given approval or if they just rejected it is by this method

```
 switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus(){
case.authorizedWhenInUse:
        print(mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)
        mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)!, zoomLevel: 12, animated: true)
        break
    case.notDetermined:
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        break
    case .restricted, .denied:
        let alertController = UIAlertController(
            title: "Background Location Access Disabled",
            message: "In order to access this feature you need to allow  to access your location while in use", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        let openAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Open Settings", style: .default, handler: {(action) in
            if let url = NSURL(string:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url as URL)
            }
        })
        alertController.addAction(openAction)
        self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        break
    default: locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }
```

I have this in three sections, one in which the user presses a button in which it zooms in on their current location, one which searches around the user, and the last is in the viewDidLoad. If the user selects the option from the prompt that sends them to their settings, and they change their location settings, when they get redirected back to my app nothing happens and if I do anything involving the users location it crashes.

I have tried using startUpdatingLocation but that doesn't do anything at all, and when I try to capture the users location from mapView.userLocation it just comes out as nil.

I have been beating my head with this all day, so any sort of help would be appreciated

Comment: Did you add NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription in plist?

Comment: Where you are writing mapView.userLocation?

Comment: Where are you checking in device? or in Simulator?

Comment: @SivajeeBattina In the case.authorizedWhenInUser I use mapView.setCenter((mapView.userLocation?.coordinate)! but it returns nil, and I am checking it in simulator

Comment: Where are you checking in device? or in Simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Try this: in Simulator choose Debug -> Location -> Some Location. And restart you app

Answer (score 0):

I also got the samething, tried with CLlocation manger's loaction property that returned 0.0000, 0.00000. Finally used didUpdateloaction